# How to add value to the table from view of another in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

Consider i have two tables namely Item and color.

The Item table contains has_many relationship with colour as each items can have more than one color but the colors are not already present.

I have a page where i have to add items and in the same page i have to specify the colors for the item. so how can i add those values to the color table along with item id. Please help me.
I am struggling to move.

**EDIT:**

Item model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :colors
end
```

Color model

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :items
    end
```

table

```
 id | created_at | updated_at | item_id | color_name 
----+------------+------------+---------+--------------
```

Comment: if you post your model and view, we could probably help you.

Comment: As i have told before, i have new.html.erb for items where i have to keep fields for color and i have to save the values for color table and also item_id for association but i do not know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the colors will always be created with item then you need to use nested attributes.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :colors_attributes
  has_many :colors
  accepts_attributes_for :colors
end
```

In your controller action `Items#new`

```
@items.colors.build
```

In  your items/new.html.erb add the fields_for with the other fields of items table.

```
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :colors do |color| %>
   <%= color.text_field :some_column_name_from_color %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For adding/removing multiple colors on the fly you can use [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

Comment: I have followed as you have told and when i go to the items/new then it displays undefined method `colors' for nil:NilClass. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The previous error came when i added accepts_nested_attributes_for :colors and when i changed to accepts_attributes_for :colors it displays undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: Sorry. Its my mistake. I have corrected and it is working perfect. Thank you so much.